# Как объект со цены FieldOfView привязать к префабу?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Я пытаюсь сделать FieldOfView и у меня все хорошо получилось, все работает, но мне нужно объект FieldOfView привязать к игроку, чтоб он следовал за ним, но вопрос, как это сделать, ибо у меня Префаб, тоесть игрока сначала нет на сцене, но спавнится потом, и как сделать чтобы он спавнился с этим объектом? Ибо просто так объект со сцены на Префаб не получается перенести
Я пробовал объект FieldOfView поставить на префаб, но тогда из префаба этот объект не передается на другой объект на сцене
[image: Скрин]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Префаб - этоф файл игры. Вы его можете разместить на ЛЮБУЮ сцену, а следовательно не можете привязать к префабу объект одной сцены, т.к. потом его можно использовать на другой, а на другой нет объекта из первой.

Привязать объект к переменной можно в ОБЪЕКТЕ префаба, созданного командой Instantiate. Понятно, что создание происходит во время игры, поэтмоу вручную вы привязать не сможете, поэтмоу делаете это, например, через GameObject.Find:

```
GetComponent<Ваш_Скрипт>().Ваша_Переменная = GameObject.Find("Название_Вашего_Объекта");
```

Comment: Тоесть, у меня вот есть скрипт Player, который расположен на префабе и мне туда нужно привязать этот объект со сцены
получается я прописываю

GetComponent<Player>().fieldOfView(название переменной, которую я задал) = GameObject.Find("Название объекта");

Я так спрашиваю, ибо непонимаю некоторых вещей, а еще разве можно объект находить по имени, или ему нужно задать Тэг?

Comment: Также у меня объект не GameObject, а FieldOfView и поэтому GameObject.FInd не работает

Comment: fieldOfView это вообще что? Вы так написали, как будто это переменная класса... Допустим, у вас есть переменная типа GameObject, называется m_obj. А на сцене есть объект с именем name_Obj.Тогда чтобы поместить m_obj в name_obj вы пишите `m_obj = GameObject.Find("name_obj")`

Comment: Для поиска по тегам есть [FindWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html) и [FindGameObjectsWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html). Первый возвращает ПЕРВЫЙ элемент в иерархии с указанным тегом, а второй - массив всех объектов с указанным тегом. Один тег может принадлежать нескольким объектам. Решайте сами, что вам самим удобнее. Иногда вообще не нужен массив, иногда важен поиск именно по тегу, чтобы, например, создать список препятствий на уровне, а иногда нужен только первый объект с определенным тегом